# Salesforce system scheduled job not executing

Tags: scheduled-tasks, salesforce

I have created a scheduler class called scheduledInsert. The scheduler Job for this class is registered with following code

```
public class TestInsertTaskScheduler
{
  public static testMethod void testInsertTaskScheduler()
  {
     scheduledInsert i = new scheduledInsert();
     Datetime now = Datetime.now();
     System.debug ('Datetime'+now);
     String sch = '0 1 * * * ?';  // scheduled to execute every minute
     system.schedule('Insert Task S3', sch, i);
     System.debug ('After schedule');
   }
}
```

The scheduled class code is

```
global class scheduledInsert implements Schedulable 
{
  global void execute(SchedulableContext SC)
  {
    System.debug('scheduled insert'); 
  }
}
```

This job (Insert Task S3) does not display under Monitoring scheduled Jobs.

Also the Job does not execute at all.

What's the mistake i am making?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm fairly sure it's because you're using a `testmethod`. When you use a `testmethod` nothing is committed to the Salesforce database; so, it would make sense that the job doesn't appear in the `Scheduled Jobs` section. Try removing the `testmethod` keyword, run it again, and see if it appears.

Comment: Thanks,
So how do i invoke the code which i have currently written in test method? This is the code which registers the job. I tried writing it in another class and invoke that function from test method.That did not work (i did feel its the same thing). The only other way i can think if is calling the function from a trigger. But i not want to keep re-registering it. Also trigger is not really obvious
regards
Sameer

Comment: I called the registerjob() from a trigger. The registered job now displays correctly under monitor-> scheduled jobs. However calling from trigger is not ideal. Is there any other way?

Comment: You don't need to call the scheduling code from a [Trigger](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_triggers.htm); you could use a [Visualforce page and an Apex Controller](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_CSH.htm#pages_controller.htm) instead. Or you could run the code from Execute Anonymous (available in the [Developer Console](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/09/new-developer-console-in-winter-12.html) or the [Force.com IDE](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation)).

Comment: Developer console worked great! Thanks. Sorry for late reply was on vacation.